# Как интегрировать YouTrack с "командными" репозиториями BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket, jetbrains, youtrack

Я сейчас пробую интегрировать Youtrack и репозитории на Bitbucket, использую для авторизации мой аккаунт. Youtrack при этом видит только мои собственные репозитории и никакого намека на командные. 
Как интегрировать Youtrack именно с командными?

Comment: Егор, вы задаёте вопрос на русскоязычном stackoveflow. Задавайте вопросы на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. На случай, если кому-нибудь понадобится: нужно в поле "Имя владельца репозитория" ввести название тимы, которую создали.